# Java Jigsaw Modules - What Happened? (July 2019)

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I get the sense that Jigsaw modules officially shipped with Java 9 in September 2017, which is almost two years ago. JDK 11 and maybe JDK 12 are widely used in production, but Jigsaw basically isn't used and isn't supported by the community and isn't ready for regular Java developers to use. The entire Java ecosystem uses build tools like Maven/Gradle/SBT that exclusively use the classic Maven style dependency system and don't use Jigsaw at all.

I have gone through the official quick start tutorial:
http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start

And that works, but it seems that the entire Java ecosystem is basically ignoring Jigsaw and for the near term, this is unlikely to change.

Is this correct? What happened?

Comment: Jigsaw solved a problem that does not exist (visibility) and did not solve a problem that *does* exist (versioned dependencies). *Edit:* It is true that replacing `rt.jar` with modules was a good move.

Comment: Why would you say that Jigsaw Modules aren't ready for regular Java developers to use? How do you define "regular Java developers" when you say that? Java Modules are ready to use for anybody who bother to learn how to use them, same as the Java language is ready for to use for any programmer bothering to learn the language.

Comment: @Andreas, are there any examples of simple "hello world" type Jigsaw projects that use third party module dependencies? I can't find any. I tried to create one that depended on slf4j-simple 1.8 (beta) and had trouble.

Comment: The advantages are also elsewhere. When you deploy a full executeable, together with a packed JRE, the result is now way smaller in size. Because you can now leave out all base modules that you never use. And that comes for free, without doing anything. Same with big frameworks that offer multiple modules, you can now just leave out everything thats not used, for free.

Answer (score 0):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959608/java-jigsaw-modules-what-happened-july-2019?noredirect=1#comment100458099_56959608):

> are there any **examples of simple "hello world" type Jigsaw projects** that use third party module dependencies? I can't find any. I tried to create one that depended on slf4j-simple 1.8 (beta) and had trouble.

From current (Jul. 9, 2019) [Logback Setup page](https://logback.qos.ch/setup.html):

> To use logback-classic in your Maven project, declare the following dependency in your project's pom file.
>
> ```xml
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
>   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
>   <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

This added the following files to my project:

```
activation-1.1.jar
javax.mail-1.6.0.jar
logback-classic-1.3.0-alpha4.jar
logback-core-1.3.0-alpha4.jar
slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta1.jar
```

*module-info.java*

```java
module Test {
    requires org.slf4j;
}
```

*test/Test.java*

```java
package test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Test {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Hello World");
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
17:00:20.132 [main] INFO test.Test - Hello World
```

Run in jdk-11.0.1 using Eclipse 2018-12.

No trouble encountered with this simple "hello world" type Jigsaw project.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote. This Answers looks spot-on to me, addressing the issues raised by the Question and Comments.

Comment: Your example doesn't even use jlink and doesn't give you the custom runtime image. That's just a plain Maven project with a Maven dependency to logback. I can get a plain old Maven project working without problems. I believe if you remove `module-info.java` nothing would change. And if you downgrade to the non-Jigsaw logback-classic 1.2.x it would run identically.